# How to generate PDF report from Python code. Odoo 16

Tags: python, pdf, odoo, report

I have a custom wizard with fields : "file_name"(Char), "model_id"(active model), "content_report"(html) .
I added a print button in this wizard .
When I click on this button I want to generate reporte with name = "file_name" and content of report = "content_report" , without using a report template. Only with python code?

How can I do it?
Any help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [_run_wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L720) function used to print the qweb reports.

***Example:***

```py
def render_html(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    
    action_report = self.env['ir.actions.report']

    pdf_content = action_report._run_wkhtmltopdf(
        [self.content_report],
        report_ref=None,
        header=header,
        footer=footer,
        landscape=False,
        specific_paperformat_args=specific_paperformat_args,
        set_viewport_size=False,
    )

    self.update({'file_content': base64.b64encode(pdf_content)})
```

*Your HTML should be enclosed in `main` tag*

Comment: Igot this error when trying this code ,have you an idea about it  please ?    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 337, in _prepare_html
    body_parent = root.xpath('//main')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that. Your HTML should be enclosed in `main` tag

Comment: What does it mean?@Kenly

Comment: Also , "file_content" is a binary field which must I added ?  @Kenly

Comment: , It means thaht the content should be by default  '<main> </main>' , please,  like this :

    def _default_content(self):
        return '''
            <main>''' + _("Start writing here...") + '''</main>
        '''
    content_report = fields.Html('Content', default=_default_content_report)

Comment: this function will printing the report ? Just calling it from wizard ?